Gradle issue after hilt update
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY`
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleSupport.createSavedStateHandle(SavedStateHandleSupport.kt:89)
                                                                                                        at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory$2.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:100)
                                                                                                        at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:170)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory.create(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:158)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl_androidKt.createViewModel(ViewModelProviderImpl.android.kt:34)

Please check this issue,After updating dependencies in gradle this issue cohave been I am stuck more than 3 days.
 gradle plugin -8.5.2
 kotlin plugin-2.0.0
 dragger plugin -2.52
 java-17


Does this help?
